# How do the intercept and slope calculated in linear regression relate to the output of lm?

Tags: linear-regression, linear-models

I have been looking at how to calculate [coefficients by hand](https://www.learnbymarketing.com/tutorials/linear-regression-by-hand-in-excel/)
and the example produces

$Y = 1,383.471380 + 10.62219546 * X$

However the output [shown of lm](https://www.learnbymarketing.com/tutorials/explaining-the-lm-summary-in-r/) does not show these values anywhere.

How do I reconcile the results of calculations by hand for B0 and B1 with the output of summary(model)?

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the values you get from manually calculating the coefficients do not show up in the output from `lm` is that `lm` is using a different dataset (Anscombe's Quartet) than the one used for manually calculating the coefficients. In addition, the regression formula also differs between the two. If using the exact same dataset and regression formula the values under the estimate column should match up by the coefficients you get from manually calculating them.